# C# Global hook Keyboard, Winform - .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, .net-6.0, keyhook

I have a question about a problem I haven't been able to solve in the past couple hours. So basically I want to make a C# WinForm app in .NET 6, and I need the app to respond to the ctrl key being pressed (It would simulate what a click of a certain button would do), but there is a catch. I need the app to sense a key pressed while being minimized. When the app is in normal state it is working, but not when minimized. A lot of other answers here were old, so I wanted to make my own, since none of the solutions worked for me, and the code was quite complicated. Thank you for any responses.

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?

Comment: @demoncrate I have tried a lot of guides here on stack overflow, as well as on youtube and some tutorials on this topic from the web.

Comment: you should look for global keyboard hook events that are accessed using references to C code. Or otherwise some background service that you communicate with.

Comment: You want to build a key logger type of application it seems. Look into that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already figured it out quite some time ago but forgot to post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to the aswer I found that worked for me.](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/573/how-to-register-a-single-or-multiple-global-hotkeys-for-a-single-key-in-winforms)

Comment: Thanks for your initiative in coming back here and posting the location of the solution. It helped me a lot!

Comment: @DiegoSayron no problem, I still go here to see the solution to the same problem ;)